# Two tier xml feeds, get data from xml link

Tags: php, xml

I use the new wordpress plugin, google xml sitemap.

Hello, lets say I have 100 posts. My sitemap xml file, instead of having 100 entries on it, has 5 links, each link linking to 20 posts.

**What I'm trying to do.. is get every name of the post into a file on my server.**

1. The sitemap.xml has this schema:
   <>sitemap
      ... <>category_location

The loc represents the 5 links, each linking to another xml file with this schema: 
    <>url
       ... <>post_name

Now, if I wanted to accest the category of links I'd do something like this:

```
$sitemap_feed = 'http://www.mysite.com/sitemap.xml';

$sitemap_xml = simplexml_load_file($sitemap_feed);

foreach( $sitemap_xml->sitemap as $xml){

$cat_location = $xml->category_location;

}
```

Now, I'd have to store all the category locations in an array, and run this code again to actually get my posts names.

```
$postname_xml = simplexml_load_file($cat_location);

foreach( $postname_xml->postname as $postname_xml){

$postname = $postname_xml->postname;

}
```

**Is there a way to do it directly? something more elegant?**

Thank you!
Hope you can understand my question:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use XPath to filter the data directly from the XML. If you could link me the XML I may be able to assist you a little bit with coding.

[XPath @ Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpath)
[Xpath explained](http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html)

Seeing your problem as resolving XML files which are mentioned inside an XML file I didn't find an easy solution on the web.

I'd go with following steps

1. Boil the URLs out of the sitemap.xml via XPath. (xpath: `//sitemap/loc`)
2. Resolve the inner XMLs and add them to a master document
3. Gather the needed information from the master document (xpath: `//postname`)

Comment: I'll give u the link quickly, cause it's an adult site, and than delete it, ok?

Comment: I see, the XML is refering others, I'll check for finding something more adequat or an gem to boil it down to one XML.

Comment: My ideea is simple, get the refering links in an array, and than use a foreach loop, tho I have a feeling there is a more elegant and practical solution for this

Comment: sadly i can't find a "resolve external xmls" I'll post a two-step code.

Comment: anything that will help is very apreciated

Comment: i think the roadmap should suffice. somehow i cant manipulate data received from your site, nor can i load it sometimes.